# What video boards can I put in a 2008 Mac Pro to get 4 monitors (DVI)?

Tags: macos, display, video

I currently have a 2008 Mac Pro with 2 Radeon HD 2600 XT video boards, each of which is driving two monitors. This setup performs acceptably, though I wouldn't be averse to faster GPUs. However, the machine periodically crashes (sometimes multiple times a day, sometimes goes for days without doing so, with no discernible pattern) with a large amount of GPU debug mode error messages in the system log. As far as I can tell, this is likely caused by either some driver bug which remains or one of the video boards is failing. This has been going on for quite some time, and while I've reported it to Apple, I don't have high hopes of it being fixed in software anytime soon.

So my question is this - what new video boards can I put in this machine that will still get me four DVI monitor hookups?

Answer (score 1):

What version of OS X? That'll be your limiting factor on GPU support, I think. The 2008 Mac Pro (3,1) had two 16x PCIe slots, so any PCIe video card *supported by your version of OS X* should work. The [official list](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2848):

Graphics cards for Mac Pro (Early 2008)

- ATI Radeon HD 2600 XT
- NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT (part number 630-9191 or 630-9897)
- NVIDIA Quadro FX 5600
- ATI Radeon HD 4870, offered as an upgrade kit

Note: The Radeon HD 4870 card requires Mac OS X v10.5.7 or later for use with the Mac Pro (Early 2008).

Graphics cards for Mac Pro (Early 2009)

- NVIDIA GeForce GT 120
- ATI Radeon HD 4870
- ATI Radeon HD 5870, offered as an upgrade kit

Note: The Radeon HD 5870 card requires Mac OS X v10.6.4 or later and it requires the use of both auxiliary power connections.

Newer cards with OS X support may work, but there are [caveats with pre-2010 Mac Pros](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3891) and I doubt they'd be officially supported.

Comment: I'm running 10.8.3, and I assume I'll upgrade to 10.9 if this hardware is supported.